# Calculating object labelling consensus area

Tags: python, computational-geometry

Scenario: four users are annotating images with one of four labels each. These are stored in a fairly complex format - either as polygons or as centre-radius circles. I'm interested in quantifying, for each class, the area of agreement between individual raters – in other words, I'm looking to get an m x n matrix, where M_i,j will be some metric, such as the IoU (intersection over union), between i's and j's ratings (with a 1 diagonal, obviously). There are two problems I'm facing.

One, I don't know what works best in Python for this. Shapely doesn't implement circles too well, for instance.

Two, is there a more efficient way for this than comparing it annotator-by-annotator?

Answer (score 0):

IMO the simplest is to fill the shapes using polygon filling / circle filling (this is simple, you can roll your own) / path filling (from a seed). Then finding the area of overlap is an easy matter.